# calling Web service in aspx page after adding reference and showing in Grid View

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have added reference of my Web Service and I want to show the data generated by Service in Grid View.

```
Test.getNew fc = new getNew();
fc.getDetail(TextBox1.Text);
```

The above code gives no result.

If I do

```
Test.getNew fc = new getNew();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds= fc.getDetail(TextBox1.Text);
```

Then above code gives an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Data.DataSet'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error clearly shows that your web method is returning System.Xml.XmlNode and you are trying to get it in Dataset.

You need to verify two things:

1. Return type of your webmethod should be the output you expect at client side, in this case dataset.
2. Your service is able to return dataset.

**EDIT**
Your solution will look like something:

```
Test.getNew fc = new getNew();
XmlNode node = fc.getDetail(TextBox1.Text);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
if (node!= null)
{
  XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(node.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Element, null); 
  dataset.ReadXml(xtr);
}
```

Then use the dataset as datasource for your control.

Comment: How should I return System.Xml.XmlNode. Can you please help me with code.

Comment: I am only having the link of the service

Comment: OK, then you can take the output in XMLNode. And then from that XMLNode you can create your own dataset.

Comment: I have done XmlNode xNode;
        xNode = fc.getDetail(TextBox1.Text); How can I create my own dataset?